# How to achieve 3D low-res effect in GameMaker:Studio 1

Tags: 3d, scaling, gml

I'm coding a 3D FPS-type game in a popular game engine called GameMaker:Studio 1.99.44. I'm trying to achieve a low-res "pixelated" effect, for example like this:

[Example of this effect in a game called "Legend of Xenia"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9V9x.gif)

I've tried experimenting with views, thus making their resolution smaller and afterwards scaling up the game window in code in hopes of achieving this effect. However the pixels scaled proportionally to the window resolution, even after I used "texture_set_interpolation(false)".

Currently my game looks like this:

[Current look of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUfga.png)

However, when I force the game to go fullscreen, the desired effect seems to appear (So, this is what I'd like to see, however in a windowed mode as well):

[Desired effect after forcing the game to go fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOO13.png)

I would really appreciate any help possible.
Thank you and have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with GMS1 as I am with GMS2 (I skipped right from GM8 to GMS2) so bear with me here.

An important concept with scaling in Game Maker has always been the difference between "room pixels" and "computer/screen/window pixels".  It seems like you understand that difference for the most part.

What you need to achieve is a disparity between the VIEW size (size in the room in "room pixels": `view_wview` and `view_hview`) and the view PORT size (size on the screen in "screen pixels": `view_wport` and `view_hport`).  You want the size of the view in the room to be really small and then the port to be several times larger (at least 4x I would guess).

You can set this up with GML code or in the room editor (see the screenshot below, taken from the GMS1 manual):

[image: View setup interface in the room editor (from the GMS1 manual)]

What may complicate this is that window size is typically pulled from room size which can be difficult to deal with when you're working with views.  One command that may help you solve this problem is `window_set_size(w,h)`.  Just be careful with doing that if you want your game to be playable on a wide range of screen resolutions (put "obligatory advice to add a resolution selector in your game menu" here).